# Bibliometrix Package looking for a ```colname``` that doesn't exist?

Tags: r

I'm running the `conceptualStructure` command using the bibliometrix package in R and sometimes I get an error `error in colnames(CW) : object "CW' not found`.

This command leads to the error.

```
> CS <- conceptualStructure(M,field="AU", method="CA", minDegree=4, clust=5, stemming=TRUE, labelsize=10)
Error in colnames(CW) : object 'CW' not found
```

While this one works as expected.
`CS <- conceptualStructure(M,field="DE", method="CA", minDegree=4, clust=5, stemming=FALSE, labelsize=10)`

The only difference is the field being used.

There is no CW column name according to the bibliometrix documentation.  Here is the list of column names that the bibliometrix package uses.

https://www.bibliometrix.org/documents/Field_Tags_bibliometrix.pdf

Could someone please explain to me why sometimes there is an error that appears to be the package looking for a column name that is not part of the package to begin with?

Thanks.

Comment: The error is not about a column named `'CW'`, rather it is asking for the column names of an object named `CW` which doesn't exist. Likely that means the function should internally make some kind of table that is called `CW`, but it hasn't done that. This sounds like a bug, or at least a very unhelpful error message.

Comment: Ah looking at [the function](https://github.com/massimoaria/bibliometrix/blob/75f663e04cebb78a88b958ad67b25a7e1e280eb4/R/conceptualStructure.R), the problem is that `field = "AU"` is not a recognized option. Perhaps you mean `"AB"`. You might suggest to the authors to check whether the field parameter supplied is actually allowed, and give an informative error otherwise.